# How to debug slow performance on hibernate/spring data getting a custom object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

So I've been fighting with getting some data in a performant manner with spring/hibernate.

Versions: `Spring Data 1.11.1.RELEASE`, `Spring 4.3.7.RELEASE`, `Hibernate 5.2.9.Final`, `Mysql Conn 5.1.41`

I have a pretty basic query

```
select ps.size*ps.pack, ps.uom, p.description, p.itemCode, ps.id as packSizeId, p.id as productId from PackSize ps
join product p on ps.product_id = p.id
where p.description like ?1
```

This query takes roughly 150 ms to run, it returns normally around 50-300 results, but it varies a bit, but those are pretty decent general numbers.

The problem I'm seeing is that it takes roughly 1 full second to process this in to actual records.

So right now my code looks like this. I've tried directly creating the MinimalPackSize via a JPQL query, and I've also tried just directly getting the real domain entity without manually crafting it. In all cases I've seen basically the same performance. It takes normally 8-10 times longer to process the results than the query takes. Which doesn't make sense why it would be that slow given how fairly few records it returns.

```
Collection<Object[]> items = internalProductRepository.findMinimalByDescriptionLike("%" + trimmed + "%");
for (Object[] item : items) {
    BigDecimal totalUnits = (BigDecimal) item[0];
    UnitOfMeasureEnum uom = UnitOfMeasureEnum.valueOf(item[1].toString());
    String desc = item[2].toString();
    String itemCode = item[3].toString();
    Long psId = ((BigInteger) item[4]).longValue();
    Long pId= ((BigInteger) item[5]).longValue();
    products.add(new MinimalPackSize(totalUnits, uom, desc, itemCode, psId, pId));
}


@Query(value = "select ps.size*ps.pack, ps.uom, p.description, p.itemCode, ps.id as packSizeId, p.id as productId from PackSize ps " +
            "join product p on ps.product_id = p.id " +
            "where p.description like ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    Collection<Object[]> findMinimalByDescriptionLike(String withDesc);
```

I've enabled debugging, and nothing stands out as being a major hog. I did verify that the `internalProductRepository.findMinimalByDescriptionLike("%" + trimmed + "%");` was what was actually slow. So it's hibernate/spring that's seem to be taking forever regardless of how I get the results.

This is on a fast machine, and I don't seem to have any other major performance issues.

Any ideas as to why it would take so long to process a few results?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a benchmark (Ex. Find out for 1 record, your code takes 1ms to process. So, for 400 records, it shouldn't go beyond 400ms). This will help to identify who is the culprit if at all you see any degradation.

And yes, You need to consider -

- the time to read the data through Jdbc driver into java objects
- the time to create objects in memory

Answer (score 1):

These are the things I would look into (in this order):

- the time you mentioned for the query, is it really for obtaining all the rows? Or just for the first couple of rows?
- The query has a bind variable. Did you actually check the time using the bind variable? Or did you replace it with a value? If the later compare the execution plans of the statement with the value and that with the bind variable. They might differ significantly.
- Get a profiler and measure, what is eating your performance.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally figured it out after using VisualVM to profile it. I had a ton of attached entities from a previous query, and on exectuing the query the entity manager checks all the existing entities to see if they need to be flushed (I have a ton of attached entities in this case). So there's a huge hit on every database call for the flush check.

I fixed my issue by moving to an unattached DTO style entity, and my perf went back to where it should have been.